# Create Event-Driven Consumer on File Endpoint without RouteBuilder in Camel 2.24

Tags: apache-camel

I want to run a processor upon file appearance in a directory. My file url is like this:

`file:{{file.root}}in?include=.*\.csv&charset=windows-1251&move=../out/done`

A procedure that associates an url with a processor is like this:

```
MessageProcessor getOrCreateConsumer(CamelContext context, String uri) {
            Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint(uri);
            endpoint.setCamelContext(context); // added this out of desperation, doesn't help
            processor = new MessageProcessor();
            try {
                Consumer consumer = endpoint.createConsumer(processor);
                endpoint.start(); // do we need this at all? works the same without it
                consumer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return processor;
    }
}
```

`MessageProcessor` is a processor that does some things to an exchange.

Everything seems to work *except* the file doesn't get moved to the `../out/done` directory. While debugging I can't get when the endpoint is configured to provide the file message exchange with this post operation.

I think I am missing some magic call that is normally invoked by a RouteBuilder and that will fully configure the file endpoint. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this programmatically? It is one of the main features of Camel to create a fully configured Endpoint out of a String URI. It just doesn't make sense to do this "manually"

Comment: @burki, was I not creating an Endpoint from a String URI? I just wanted to avoid the RouteBuilder, that what I was calling "manually". Will update the question.

Comment: But the Routes are a very central Camel concept, why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: You need to done the UoW on the Exchange to have the file moved. ExchangeHelper.doneUnitOfWork.